# Is transition into consultancy a one way street?

Tags: career-switch, consulting, pharma-industry

I am considering a transition from a  manager position in a big multinational life science company to a senior manager level position in a consultancy firm, again a big multinational company that is active and expanding within life sciences.

As I weigh the pros and cons of such a change at age 40 or so, I wonder if such a move would limit my career options moving forwards, ie. if the transition would look negatively by other companies outside the consultancy sphere, if I were to decide that consultancy isn’t my cup of tea or if I were to change jobs based on other considerations like location or remote/hybrid etc

Answer (score 48):

You're not becoming a consultant, you're moving from one manager position to another manager position. This doesn't affect your career options much at all.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to [Kilisi's entirely correct answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/194837/14273) -- management is management, especially within the same industry -- even moving to true consultancy is not a one-way street.

I've seen consultants hired in when a company decided they wanted their skills on a longer-term basis, and consulting on a resume is not a deal breaker; it gets evaluated, like anything else on the resume, in terms of what skills and successes you can report.

Comment: I fully agree. It is possible that consultants get paid so well that no-one can afford to hire them full-time, but that is a) a good problem to have and b) doesn't make you unemployable, it just means you have to take a massive salary hit if you ever decide to go back. A friend told me they sometimes hire a consultant who charges 4000+ € / day. They hire him, despite being 10x more expensive than others, because he also solves their problems 20–100x faster than others, but they could never afford to hire him full-time … nor do they need his expertise more often than every couple of years.

Comment: There are plusses and minuses to being a consultant, discussed in other Answers. I know multiple people who have moved back and forth depending on how much security they needed at that point in their lives and how interesting/prestigious the project was.

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not a one-way street. I have a bunch of consultants in my circles and there are several who have moved from consulting into non-consulting positions. Often at former client companies.

As others have outlined, you appear to not even move into a consulting position, only into a consulting company. That's not the same thing.